# What does "*(Vector2*)&x"; in C++ mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, strict-aliasing, type-punning

I'm currently watching this tutorial on unions in C++, and here is a snippet of code provided by the [Youtuber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uqU9Y578n4):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Vector2
{
     float x, y;
};

struct Vector4
{
     float x, y, z, w;
     Vector2& GetA() 
     {
         return *(Vector2 *)&x;
     }

};

void PrintVector2(const Vector2& vector)
{
    std::cout << vector.x << ", ", << vector.y << std::endl;
}
```

I am particularly confused at this part here:

```
Vector2& GetA() 
    {
         return *(Vector2 *)&x;
     }
```

What exactly is going on here?

Here is my attempt to try to understand it.

So we are grabbing the address of `x`, and then assigning it to be a pointer of `Vector2` type, and then dereferencing it. Why do we not just, `return &x`? I'm also confused at how you can type coerce the address of `x` into a `Vector2` type.

Comment: `&x` has type `float*` - which is very different from a `Vector2&`

Comment: It does invalid cast leading to UB.

Comment: This code is garbage. It is literally meaningless (the C++ standard assigns no meaning to the code). I would stop watching that particular youtuber.

Comment: "I'm also confused at how you can type coerce the address of x into a Vector2 type." you cannot

Comment: Your interpretation is somewhat off however. It does not assign the pointer to a `Vector2*` it **casts** it to a `Vector2*` That is it forces the compiler to interpret a pointer to one type, as a pointer to another type. You also seem confused about the return type, `Vector2&` is a **reference** to a `Vector2` object not a pointer. That's why the dereference is necessary.

Comment: "Undefined behaviour" includes "apparently working fine", to this might in dead appear to work.

Comment: Offending line can be rewritten as `*reinterpret_cast<Vector*>(&x)` or `reinterpret_cast<Vector&>(x)` if C++ notation is clearer.

Comment: for context: The video is about unions and the code you refer to is only on the screen for a short while where the author says "It could be this", but then they use the union. Not sure if they intentionally said "could" rather than "can". Anyhow, I agree that this video seems to create more confusion than it does explain. And if it does not conclude with refering you to `std::variant` then it isnt worth what you pay for it.

Comment: What you really need to watch out for is the `(Vector2 *)` is a C-Style cast. It is effectively the word of god to the compiler. No matter how invalid the reinterpretation of the variable is, the compiler will trust the programmer and generate code that does it. All of the errors and warnings are turned off, so the programmer has to be absolutely certain that the result will be correct. If they are wrong, happy debugging. When ever you see one of these babies in code, check it carefully because you could be looking at a bug hiding in plain sight.

Comment: I believe this question needs more focus.  Do you know what `x` means?  Do you know what `&x` means?  `Vector2`?  C style casts?  Pointers?  Pointer dereferences?

Answer (score 2):

It means nothing more, nothing less than Undefined Behaviour. What the author attempted to do is tell compiler "treat `this` instance of `Vector4` as instance of `Vector2`", but that's plain **wrong** way to do so.

Breaking it down into pieces:
First they get address of the first member of `this`

```
&x
```

Then they do a C-style cast, throwing whole type system out of the window to tell compiler "shut up, this pointer points to `Vector2`"

```
(Vector2*) &x
```

Finally they dereference the pointer, now treated by compiler as `Vector2`:

```
* (Vector2*) &x
```

Answer (score 2):

The code tells the compiler to pretend that the address of `x` (i.e., `float*`) is actually the address of an object of type `Vector2`. Of course, it's not, and the compiler is not required to do anything that makes the result seem sensible. Whoever wrote that assumed that the `float x, y` in `Vector2` and the `float x, y, z, w` in `Vector4` have some mystic connection that will make the beginning of that `Vector4` member data look like a `Vector2` object. There is nothing in the language definition that requires this to work.

Comment: Does not the standard allow `reinterpret_cast` between "standard layout" structs in a situation where the destination data members match the first members of the source?

Comment: @Eugene -- you may be right, but I'm not sure. What I see (I haven't been paying attention lately) is that you can convert a pointer to a standard layout class into a pointer to its first element. Can you find something more?

Comment: No, probably you are right and conversion to the pointer to the first member is the only guarantee.